# Why is LiFi supposibly faster than WiFi?

Tags: visible-light, radio

It is claimed that [LiFi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li-Fi) (a data-transfer technology that works with visible light) - much faster than WiFi, how is that - if both are basically an EM radiation wave (WiFi is radio)? Shouldn't the same techniques used in Lifi can simply be applied to Wifi?

It works by "flickering" light (changing amplitudes?), but why can't thr same technique be used in radio waves?

Comment: Please provide a reference for said claim - is it claimed that the time sent data takes from the source to the receivers is shorter, or just that the data transferred per second is higher, which is what we usually mean by a fast data transfer and which has nothing to do with the speed of the means of transmission?

Comment: for example: http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/lifi-internet-breakthrough-224gbps-connection-broadcast-led-bulb-1488204

Answer (score 5):

Maximum data rate depends on power, bandwidth, and ambient noise, see  [Shannon Hartley Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem). Using light gives one far more bandwidth (although current technology of light modulation has certain practical limitations), allowed power, and there often is less background noise. So in theory it can move data faster. However, there are quite a few practical differences/problems like typically more multipath (light bounces off of most everything), less channelization, some environments have a lot of light noise, etc.

Comment: +1 but if you think the claim **is** correct, this question might deserve a  longer treatment, as a lot of folks might find it interesting

Comment: @glS do you know what bandwidth means and how it relates to data rate? Your comment is sort of asking for a derivation of the Shannon theorem because once you understand that the rest files easily. Or are your asking why visible light physically can be used at higher bandwidth?

Comment: So, basically, light has bigger bandwidth because it has more "available frequencies" than radio, and it transfer data faster because it uses more simultanious "channels" (frequencies)?